# Double integral $\int_{[0,1]^2} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} dx\,dy$ for regular function $f$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $f$ be a sufficiently regular function on the unit square. (For example, say $f\in C^1$.)
Then, is there a way to simplify the integral
$$\int_{[0,1]^2} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} dx\,dy ?$$
If $f\in C^1$, then the integrand is bounded and therefore the integral is well-defined.

Comment: The integral can be represented as $$\int_{[0,1]^3} f'((x-y)z+y)\:dz\:dy\:dx$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote the quantity in question by $Q$. Due to symmetry it is sufficient to integrate over $\>T\!: \ 0\leq y<x\leq1$. Furthermore we write
$$f(x)-f(y)=\int_y^xf'(t)\>dt\ .$$
We then have
$$Q=2\int_T \left( {1\over x-y}\int_y^x f'(t)\>dt\right)\> {\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^t \int_t^1{2\over x-y}\>dx\>dy\right) f'(t)\>dt\ .$$
We now have to compute the weight function
$$\eqalign{h(t) &:= 2\int_0^t \int_t^1 {1\over x-y}\>dx\>dy\cr
&=2\int_0^t \log(x-y)\biggr|_{x=t}^{x=1}\>dy=2\int_0^t \bigl(\log(1-y)-\log(t-y)\bigr)\>dy\ ,\cr} $$
so that one obtains
$$h(t)=2 \left(t\log{1\over t}+(1-t)\log{1\over 1-t}\right)\ .$$
The plot of $h(t)$ is a symmetric bump over the interval $[0,1]$. The final answer therefore is
$$Q=\int_0^1 h(t)\>f'(t)\>dt\ .$$

Comment: That is a nice formula!